# Running PNPM installation in git submodule fails for "ERR_PNPM_OUTDATED_LOCKFILE"

Tags: git, pnpm, pnpm-workspace

I created a monorepo project using `pnpm workspaces`.
I cloned it using `git clone --recurse-submodules git@github.com:blabla/project.git .`
In my root folder, I have `pnpm-workspace.yaml` file:

```yaml
packages:
    - 'apps/*'
```

I also have `pnpm-lock.yaml` file in the root folder and `package.json`.

In my `apps` folder, I have a git submodule repository as well: `apps/example`. In this submodule repository, there is a PNPM project also, with `apps/example/package.json` and `apps/example/pnpm-lock.yaml` file. When I tried to install dependencies in this submodule project by running:

```bash
cd ./apps/example
pnpm i --frozen-lockfile --prefer-offline
```

I get this error: `ERR_PNPM_OUTDATED_LOCKFILE  Cannot install with "frozen-lockfile" because pnpm-lock.yaml is not up to date with apps/example/package.json`

It seems like PNPM tried to relate the root pnpm project.

**If I clone only the submodule repository, by "normal clone":** `git clone git@github.com:blabla/example.git`, and then run `pnpm i --frozen-lockfile --prefer-offline` it succeeds.

I tried also to run this script in the root folder of the pnpm workspace project:

```bash
rm ./pnpm-lock.yaml
cd ./apps/example
pnpm i --frozen-lockfile --prefer-offline
```

But then I got this error:

```
 ERROR  Headless installation requires a pnpm-lock.yaml file
```

How can I resolve this issue?